# Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one ,But i did

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-query

i'm new to react querys followed the documentation and i get the problem that i implemented correctly help is appreciated

error:

> Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query'
import axios from 'axios';


    const queryClient = new QueryClient()
    
    export default function App() {
      const queryInfo =
        useQuery('pokemon', () => axios
          .get('https://pokeapi.com/api/v2/pokemon')
          .then(res => res.data.results))
    
      return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          {queryInfo.data?.map(result => {
            return <div key={result.name}>{result.name}</div>
          })}
        </QueryClientProvider>
      )
    }
```

Comment: None of the [search results for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22No%20QueryClient%20set%2C%20use%20QueryClientProvider%20to%20set%20one%22%20site%3Astackoverflow.com) helped to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have created a `queryClient`, but you are still using `useQuery` *outside* of the `<QueryClientProvider>`. Every call to `useQuery` must be *inside* the Provider:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient()
export default function App() {
return (
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <Something />
  </QueryClientProvider>
}

function Something() {
  const queryInfo =
    useQuery('pokemon', () => axios
      .get('https://pokeapi.com/api/v2/pokemon')
      .then(res => res.data.results))

  return queryInfo.data?.map(result => {
    return <div key={result.name}>{result.name}</div>
  }) ?? null
}
```